# how to wait perform tasks in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have a question how to wait perform several tasks that are in some method even that method is called few times in different threads;

For example:

When I call method:

1:

2:

I want to see the following:

1:
STEP 1, STEP 2;

2:
STEP 1, STEP 2;

but often I see the following:

1:
2:
STEP 1, STEP 1,
STEP 2, STEP 2,

See code below, maybe it helps to understand the problem better;

```
//many times per second
- (void)update:(UpdateObjectClass *)updateObject {    
    //step 1:
    //update common data(for example array)
    //long process(about 1-2 seconds)
    [self updateData:updateObject];

    //step 2:
    //update table
    [self updateTableView];
}
```

I have tried to use `dispatch_barrier_async`, but I don't understand how to use this in proper way;

Thank you for any help ;)

Comment: Insufficient info. Please show actual code and actual logging demonstrating out-of-order execution and showing thread numbers.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you are calling `-[update:]` multiple times per second, but you want it to run synchronously (i.e. once-at-a-time; not parallel)?

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly;

Comment: It can be asynchronously but order has to be always the same - step 1; step 2

Comment: @O.Daniel if it's done asynchronously, there's no guarantee that it will always be done in the same order – which is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm borrowing from @remus's answer.

Assuming that `-[update:]` is being called on the same instance of an object (and not a whole bunch of objects), you can use `@synchronized` to enforce that your code is only performed one-at-a-time.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    @synchronized(self) {
        // Run your updates
        // [self updateData:updateObject];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            // Async thread callback:
            [self updateTableView];
        });
    }
});
```

### However

I am going to go out on a limb, and guess that the reason you need this code to be performed synchronously is because your `-[updateData:]` method is doing something that is *not* thread safe, such as modifying a `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`. If this is the case, you should really use that `@synchronized` trick on the **mutable thing itself**.

I highly recommend that you post the code to `-[updateData:]` if it is not too long.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve the problem at the wrong level and with the information in the question it is unlikely that any solution can be provided.

Given the output reported we know that `updateData` and `updateTableView` are asynchronous and use one *or more* tasks. We don't know anything about what queue(s) they use, how many tasks they spawn, whether they have an outer task which does not complete until sub tasks have, etc., etc.

If you look at the standard APIs you will see async methods often take a completion block. Internally such methods may use multiple tasks on multiple queues, but they are written such that all such tasks are completed before they call the completion block. Can you redesign `updateData` so it takes a completion block (which you will then use to invoke `updateTableView`)?

The completion block model doesn't by itself address all the ways you might need to schedule a task based on the completion of other task(s), there are other mechanisms including: serial queues, dispatch groups and dispatch barriers.

Serial queues enable a task to be scheduled after the completion of all other tasks previously added to the queue. Dispatch groups enable multiple tasks scheduled on multiple queues to be tagged as belonging to a group, and a task scheduled to run after all tasks in a group have completed. Dispatch barriers enable a task to be scheduled after all previous tasks scheduled on a concurrent queue.

You need to study these methods and then embed the appropriate ones for your needs into your design of `updateData`, `updateTableView` and ultimately `update` itself. You can use a bottom up approach, essentially the opposite of what your question is attempting. Start at the lowest level and ask whether one or more tasks should be a group, have a barrier, be sequential, and might need a completion block. Then move " upward".

Probably not the answer you were hoping for! HTH

Comment: Thank you for answer; Maybe, the main problem is that there are about 600 lines of code and I cannot send all of them in my post; What I have done: first one I synchronized code by self; Second - after that all my changes I do in main thread; It has helped me perform all tasks in correct order;

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `dispatch_async` to run the array updates and then update your tableView. You can do this inside of a single method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    // Run your updates
    // [self updateData:updateObject];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // Async thread callback:
        [self updateTableView];
    });
});
```

**Edit**

I'd consider modifying your `updateData` method to run inside the async queue; when it is done, call `[self updateTableView];` directly from that method. If it's not too long, can you add the `[self updateData:updateObject]` code (or a portion of) to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, your approach doesn't work; I put NSLog after `updateData` and after `updateTableView` and what I see: _updateData, updateData, updateData_ and in the end _updateTableView_ calling; I have to have strong consistency - 1, 2;

Comment: Ah, because your updateObject doesn't have a callback in itself. See edit.

Comment: @remus since you posted your edit, OP clarified that he needs the `-[update:]` call to be performed one-at-a-time – not concurrently. In other words, he needs to call `-[updateTableView]` before calling `-[updateData:]` again.